# Laravel remember_token exists but still error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am doing some authentication but the remember_token always errors out, it is in the database as a varchar(100) and nullable. the functions are in the user model (see below) but when I'm calling Auth::logout() it gives me the `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list'` error. What am I doing wrong?

```
/**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
```

I don't really know what code you need, so if you need any, please ask!

The logout code:

```
public function getLogout($token){
        if($token != '{token}' . csrf_token()){
            echo 'FAIL';
            return;
        }
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::route('home');
    }
```

Here's the database column:
[image: Remeber_token collumn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `remember_token` column to your `users` table.

Please refer to the Laravel [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26).

## Edit (further to your last Edit):

[image: Remeber_token collumn]

It should be `remember_token` instead of **remeber_token** as @TheShiftExchange warned :-)

Comment: are you sure rhbvkleef? did you run the migration to actually interest the column? double check the spelling?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange check the picture I just added.